# "Polling fails" observed in US elections quantified as right- or left-leaning?

Tags: united-states, election, political-spectrum, political-science, polling

Define a *polling fail* s.t.

1. a particular candidate *C*, running in ...
2. a particular election *E*, s.t. ...
3. pre-*E* polls (collectively, averaged) predict *C* to achieve vote share *S<sub>0</sub>*, but ...
4. results from *E* give *C* vote share *S<sub>1</sub>*, s.t. ...
5. *S<sub>0</sub>* differs significantly from *S<sub>1</sub>* (*(S<sub>0</sub> << S<sub>1</sub>) || S<sub>0</sub> >> S<sub>1</sub>)*)

Observers of US politics often find instances of polling fails s.t.

> *[type A]* (*C* is generally perceived to be "left of center"**[1]**) *&& (S<sub>0</sub> >> S<sub>1</sub>)*

i.e., a US correlate of the UK ["shy Tory factor"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shy_Tory_factor). A recent US instance (as of 4 Nov 2020) is the [2020 election for US president](https://web.archive.org/web/20201102205052/https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/2020-election-forecast/). There are however cases where "politically-opposite" behavior has been observed, s.t.

> *[type B]* (*C* is generally perceived to be "right of center"**[2]**) *&& (S<sub>0</sub> >> S<sub>1</sub>)*

such as the [2012 US presidential election](https://web.archive.org/web/20140829072035/https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2012/nov/21/2012-election-polling-skewed-for-mitt-romney), where the "left-of-center" candidate outperformed his pre-election polls.**[3]**.

**My question is:** have polling fails as defined here been studied both quantitatively *and* with regard to left-right political orientation/spectrum? I'm looking for pointers to studies that (e.g.) classify polling fails in a manner similar to my type A and type B (above), and which then compare the numbers of each.

---

**[1]**: In US political classification, "left of center" typically includes Democrats as well as persons labeled "liberal" or "progressive." (This is a characterization, not an equation!)
**[2]**: In US political classification, "right of center" typically includes Republicans as well as persons labeled "libertarian" or "conservative." (Ditto.)
**[3]**: It's also a case of a US-minority-ethnicity candidate reversing the ["Bradley effect"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bradley_effect), though there are certainly more recent instances (as of 4 Nov 2020) combining both the Bradley and shy-Tory effects (e.g., the [Graham-Harrison 2020 election for US senator from SC](https://web.archive.org/web/20201103044305/https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/polls/south-carolina/)).

Comment: Probably worth reading https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/the-polls-werent-great-but-thats-pretty-normal/ Observation "The reason there’s no long-running polling bias is because pollsters try to correct for their mistakes. That means there’s always the risk of undercorrecting or overcorrecting."

Comment: Can you write this less confusingly?

Answer (score 5):

538 does a good job of [analysing polls:](https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/the-polls-werent-great-but-thats-pretty-normal/)

```
YEAR    FINAL AVERAGE   RESULT  ERROR
1972    R+24            R+23    -1
1976    D+1             D+2     -1
1980    R+2             R+10    +8
1984    R+18            R+18    0
1988    R+10            R+8     -2
1992    D+7             D+6     +1
1996    D+13            D+9     +4
2000    R+4             D+1     -5
2004    R+2             R+2     0
2008    D+7             D+7     0
2012    D+0             D+4     -4
2016    D+4             D+2     +2
2020    D+8             D+4*    +4
```

Pollsters do attempt to correct for their previous errors which is why there isn't a general trend of favouring Republicans or Democrats.  The linked article also notes that attempts to correct for "shy tories" in 2017 resulted in a polling error the other way.

Pollsters try to weight their samples so that bias and errors are reduced. I see no long term or clear bias in the above numbers.

Comment: 538’s Nate Silver also noted this week that we don’t have final votes for 2020 yet, so that 4 point gap may change.

Comment: Its currently closer to 4.5, the 4 point gap assumes it will tighten slightly as the final votes are counted.